# Java json object deserialized unknown instance to priory

Tags: java, json, deserialization, instanceof

i have a `class Myobject{ String object; }`, into string object i can insert into a one class between this classes: `class A{....}` , `class B{....}` , `class C{....}` serialized into json format. My problem is to known the instance of class that is been insert into field object of MyObject because i don't know the class before the deserialization. How i can to resolve the problem? Sorry for my english and if there is a problem into a formulation of this answer because i'm a new user.
Thanks in advance for responses.

Comment: Use the 'instanceof' operator.

Comment: "instanceof" operator i can't to use because i'm doing a deserialization and it reply a instance of String and no a instance of A or B or C

Comment: What does your class look like when it's been serialized?

Comment: Example: the client serialize the class A and it insert into field object, send  MyObject to server, the server would deserialized the field object but it don't know that the class into string object is the type A

Comment: Can you provide an actual example of the JSON that you insert into `object`?

Comment: It all depends on the serialization format. Standard java serialization stores the data type in the serialized data and uses it for deserialization. Are you using something standard?

Comment: Example:  A might be {"name":"joshep"},  B might be {"name":"ilary","salary":"2000"} and C might be {"name":"fabrice", "type":"student"}. This three class are different. I create into client for example: MyObject(A) ---> MyObject("{"name":"joshep"}"); --> {"object":"{\"name\":\"joshep\"}"}. Next, into server receive MyObject("{"name":"joshep"}"); --> {"object":"{\"name\":\"joshep\"}"} and it deserialize but it don't know that the class into field Object (String) is the type A. Can't from {\"name\":\"joshep\"} obtain A